# Where to put the SSH login info in rsync command?

Tags: rsync

I need some help getting my rync command syntax working. I need to clone the `/home/user/public_html` folder on a remote server to the server I am logged into via SSH, copying the folder into the same exact path on this local machine.

I have root on the local machine I'm in session on and a user account shell on the remote machine. I'm not clear on where to put the SSH login info and how to define the folder paths.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

run:

```
rsync -avz user@remoteMachine:/home/user/public_html /home/user/public_html
```

Comment: I managed to figure it out via trial and error but this is the correct command. One note for future google searches - I had already set up the domain to be moved and kept getting empty files from rsync. It was resolving the local host as the domain, I had to use the remote IP to finally get the transfer to work. (Same user and pass on both machines for the domain created part of the problem). It was just "sending" the local files back to itself. That one had me confused for an hour or so...

Answer (score 1):

`rsync -urltv -e ssh user@remote:public_html /home/user/public_html`

Comment: rsync on any Linux distro released in the last five years defaults to ssh. -e ssh is only needed if you're trying to set ssh flags like -i or change the encryption.

Comment: @kashani, the entire world doesn't use Linux, and the questioner didn't specify.  My way is portable.

Comment: heh, alright if you can find an OS shipped in the last five years where you need to specify the -e ssh I'll upvote you. Definitely not needed on BSD, Solaris, or OSX.

Comment: The reason this command did not work is that the public_html folder is not in the user's shell home. The user had access to the full / path so the full path was needed to make the transfer work. For some reason they had set up the user's actual home in a folder in / rather than the system /home folder which also created some confusion on my part of a while.