# Sync files between two computers connected to same network using rsync command

Tags: bash, unix, rsync

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Need help w/ rsync](https://serverfault.com/questions/236602/need-help-w-rsync)

I have two computers connected to the same network, say Computer A and Computer B.
Computer A has some backup files in a directory that needs to be synched to Computer B(an exact mirror has to be created). Here the condition is I have to do this using **rsync** command.
How can I do this? Should I have to do this using hostname of the computers.
Please help me at the earliest.
Thanks in advance

Comment: The rsync manual is pretty clear, and this is one of the most basic use cases. What have you tried?

Comment: Thanks for the reply ceejayoz. Im a learner still, I dont know to this .Can you give me an example.

Comment: If you're a learner then make the effort to learn. Start by reading about the commands you use. On Linux/Unix there will be one or more man pages for each. i.e. type "man rsync" at the command prompt, or type it into Google.

Answer (score 2):

```
rsync src_user@src_hostname:src_dir/ trg_user@target_hostname:target_dir/
```

for options check

```
rsync --help
```

or

```
man rsync
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Lysergia. But, Im not able to get the t syntax for this. I'm using this for now.But nothing seems to be working.

Comment: What is wrong? Can you post the command you tried?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to make it automatic you must cover some basics.

1st rsync connects trough ssh. You have to make sure the user, which you will use for rsyncing has ssh key installed on the remote computer (I will use user "root" as example).

2nd make a decision how exactly you will rsyncing (from the server to the backup-server or from the backup-server to the server)
I'll do it as the script is running on the backup server.

- Generate key on the backup-server (run the command)

  ```
  $ ssh-keygen
  ```
- Copy the generated key to the remote (server which files have to be copied) computer :

  ```
  $ ssh-copy-id -i /root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub root@server-ip:
  ```

now your server will connect to the remote server without asking for password.
from here you can make something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
## Rsync script
###
PATH=/usr/bin:
rsync -auvz root@server-ip:/path/to/directory/ /backup-server/path/to/backup/
```

be aware of the fact that:

1. if you place a "/" at the end of the paths it means "synchronize the CONTENT of that directory" `( /path/to/dir/ )`
2. if you don't place a "/" it will rsync the whole directory    `( /path/to/dir )`